# SocialGap plugin for cordova doesn't load the login page in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, linkedin-api

Im using SocialGap plugin in cordova to do login with linkedin , 
it working when i deploy to Android device , but when trying in IOS emulator it shows a blink page but for other pages like when i put a wrong Client_ID it shows that error normally

This is what i get :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys , for anyone who have the same issue , i just tried by my self and found that if you remove the scope parameter from the url of authentication the url will load correctly in ios and Android , just change it from Javascript configuration of the plugin it self . 
That it .